# Joined Server Site refuses to launch post Federation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise, federation

We have a server site with web adaptor installed on machine A and there is another machine B with server installed and joined to machine A.

We are observing that after federating machine A with portal (on machine C), machine B just goes into please wait mode. If we un-federate machine A this issue does not happen and machine B works fine. What is triggering this? We tried reinstalling, issue persist.

I did raised this on ESRI Community to seek some ideas. https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/joined-server-site-refuses-to-launch-post/m-p/1379782#M38547

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this would be worth logging a job with ESRI support.

Comment: Sure, we can check with ESRI Tech Support, but @SonofaBeach, can you confirm if this is not an expected behavior and server manager for a joined site must launch after federation?